# java split string with regular expression

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a string like "~~banana~apple~". I want to split that string with "~" is seperator and i want last element in the array after split is "" not "apple".

```
        String fruits = "~~banana~apple~";
        String[] arr = fruits.split("~");
        String last = "";  //Last string i need
        if (arr.length > 0 )
            last =  arr[arr.length-1];

        System.out.println("last: " + last);
```

//The result

last: apple

//but i want in this case the value of last must be "" because afer "apple" have "~".

Sorry my bad english.

Comment: If apple isn't what you want, what do you want?

Comment: The value is in `fruits` variable and you are splitting `ten` variable. Is that a typo or partial code.

Comment: There is nothing after your last `~` so there's nothing to point to as the last element.

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel i want it must be an empty string because after apple have "~"

Comment: @Subir Kumar Sao Sorry i copy and forget to edit to English varriable (ten = Name in English)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are looking for `split("~",-1)`. By default `split` removes empty strings (`""`) from the end, but with negative limit it will leave them.